# Is it possible to use gmail from node.js app without `LESS SECURED APPS`

Tags: node.js, email, gmail

No support for my account for `LESS SECURED APPS`.

I always use this but not any more.

```js
const shared = require("./../common/shared");
const config = require("./../config");
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

class Sender {
  constructor(to, subject, content) {
    this.userId = shared.formatUserKeyLiteral(to);
    this.subject = subject;
    this.to = to;
    this.content = content;
  }

  async SEND(subject) {

    let arg = {
      user: "greespiral@gmail.com",
      pass: "***",
      to: this.to,
      subject: this.subject,
      html: this.content
    }

    console.log('EMAIL')

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      port: 587,
      secure: false,
      auth: {
        user: "greespiral@gmail.com",
        pass: "****",
      }
  });

  transporter.verify(function (error, success) {
    if(error) {
        console.log("NOT PREPARE EMAIL !!!!" + error);
    } else {
        console.log('Server validation done and ready for messages.')
    }
});

const email = {
  from: 'greespiral@gmail.com',
  to: 'zlatnaspirala@gmail.com',
  subject: 'ROCKET',
  text: 'Now is the time for all good men to send Email via Node.js!'
};

  transporter.sendMail(email, function(error, success){
    if (error) {
        console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>' + error);
    } else {
        console.log('Nodemailer Email sent: ' + success.response);
    }
});



    // return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //   this.GM = require("gmail-send")(arg);
    //   this.GM((
    //     subject
    //     // files: [filepath],
    //   ), function(err, res) {
    //     if (err != null) { reject(err); }
    //     resolve(res);
    //   });
    // });

  }

}
module.exports = (to, subject, content) => { return new Sender(to, subject, content) }
```

ERROR:

```js
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn m
ore at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials z6-20020a170906814600b00992a8a5
4f32sm1399961ejw.139 - gsmtp
NOT PREPARE EMAIL !!!!Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Le
arn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b17-20020aa7cd11000000b0052241b
8fd0bsm1441933edw.29 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Gmail is no longer being supported for Less secure apps from May 30, 2022. Now the Gmail API uses OAuth2 authentication with Tokens for authentications to help keep accounts secure.

More Information

[Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Here is and quick start guide for OAuth2 authentication implementation from Google documentation.

[Quick Start Guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)